# How do you style multiple elements inside a polymer element?

Tags: css, polymer

I have a simple problem.  I am trying to understand how styling works with nested elements.

I have 4 elements bundled into 1 and I want to arrange those 4 elements across in a row from left to right.

here is what have:  http://jsbin.com/kowak/1/edit

I do not understand how to call individual elements in the styling of the main element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic CSS questions. You can tell the `Resume-Header` element to be a flex container which achieves the layout:

```
<style>
  :host {
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
```

http://jsbin.com/lakatiqe/1/edit